# To find what object is underneath our touch when touch moved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How to determine the property or perhaps the object underneath the object i am hovering or dragging?

To put my question clearly, lets take I am hovering a uiview, I want to find out what (object or view) is underneath the view I am hovering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in custom view you can override touchesEnded method.This sample code may help your custom view hit test problem.

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

            if ([touches count] == 1) {
                UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
                CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:custom_view];

                if (CGRectContainsPoint(custom_view.bounds, point)) {
                   //if touch hit to custom_view
                };
            }
            [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, if you know the frames of both objects you can use `CGRectIntersectsRect`.

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(topObjectsRect, bottomObjectsRect)) {
        //
    }
```

Additionally, you could get the point that was touched and then use the following to check if that point is in a certain rectangle.

```
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(someX, someY, someWidth, someHeight), pointOfTouch))
  {
      //
  }
```